# How to show list of last 10 month in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to show last 10 month from current month in my project. I have tried this

```
    <?php
$months = array();
for ($i=1; $i<11; $i++) {
 $months[$i."_".date('Y', strtotime('-'.$i.' Month'))] = date('M', strtotime('-'.$i.' Month'));
}
```

its gives me

```
   Array
(
    [1_2016] => Jun
    [2_2016] => May
    [3_2016] => Apr
    [4_2016] => Mar
    [5_2016] => Feb
    [6_2016] => Jan
    [7_2015] => Dec
    [8_2015] => Nov
    [9_2015] => Oct
    [10_2015] => Sep
)
```

but the `index` `month` no is wrong i want this

```
Array
(
    [6_2016] => Jun
    [5_2016] => May
    [4_2016] => Apr
    [3_2016] => Mar
    [2_2016] => Feb
    [1_2016] => Jan
    [12_2015] => Dec
    [11_2015] => Nov
    [10_2015] => Oct
    [9_2015] => Sep
)
```

Comment: Can you use mysql query in your code or normal for loop (PHP code) is necessary ?

Comment: Actually i have to show a dropdown of last 8 month to my users screen whenever they select any month then i will run query by getting month and year by selected key of month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
$dateArray = array();
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) { 
    $dateArray[date('m_Y', strtotime("-$i month"))] = date('M', strtotime("-$i month"));
} 
print_r($dateArray);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [06_2016] => Jun
    [05_2016] => May
    [04_2016] => Apr
    [03_2016] => Mar
    [02_2016] => Feb
    [01_2016] => Jan
    [12_2015] => Dec
    [11_2015] => Nov
    [10_2015] => Oct
    [09_2015] => Sep
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `$i`

```
$months[$i."_".
```

you need to use `date` function like as

```
$months[date('n',strtotime('-'.$i.' Month'))."_"
```

Comment: Please use `intval(date('m', strtotime('-'.$i.' Month')))` instead ! 06 -> 6 ;)

Comment: I think we can simply use `n` instead of `m`

Comment: Yes I missed that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just use date format and strtotime of month subtraction

```
$months = array();
for ($i=1; $i<11; $i++) {
 $months[date('n_Y', strtotime('-'.$i.' Month'))] = date('M_Y', strtotime('-'.$i.' Month'));
}
var_dump($months);
```

Date format

> Y - A four digit representation of a year
>
> n - A numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros (1 to 12)
>
> M - A short textual representation of a month (three letters)